# Selecionar apenas 1 registro por mes com um agravante que impede o uso do Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso trazer apenas a venda mais antiga do cliente, independente do tipo da venda, porém eu preciso que o tipo da venda venha no `select`, antes eu tive uma duvida semelhante e me ajudaram aqui no StackOverflow, porém aumentando o nivel dos estudos, cheguei nesse problema.

Antes eu tinha a seguinte `query` e funcionava, porém eu não tinha o "tipo" da venda, tendo agora o tipo da venda, impossibilita o uso do `Group By`, como eu poderia fazer:

```
SELECT 
    loja, 
    nome, 
    MONTH(data) 
    MIN(data) 
FROM vendas
GROUP BY loja, nome, MONTH(data)
```

Preciso obter o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fica aqui uma possível solução usando o ROW_NUMBER() ou o DENSE_RANK():

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
   SELECT loja, 
          nome,
          tipo, 
          data,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY nome, loja ORDER BY data ASC, tipo) RN    
     FROM vendas
)
SELECT loja, 
       nome,
       tipo, 
       data
       MONTH(data)
  FROM CTE
 WHERE RN = 1
```

Note que a query anterior devolve a venda mais antiga por cliente, por loja, caso existam duas vendas com a mesma data, irá devolver um registo "aleatório".

Se pretender, por exemplo, retornar todas as vendas que ocorreram nessa data minima, pode usar o DENSE_RANK().

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
   SELECT loja, 
          nome,
          tipo, 
          data,   
          DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY nome, loja ORDER BY data ASC, tipo) DS
     FROM vendas
)
SELECT loja, 
       nome,
       tipo, 
       data
       MONTH(data)
  FROM CTE
 WHERE DS = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso de diversas maneiras.
O problema vai ser se você tiver mais de uma venda no mesmo dia.

```
SELECT i.loja, 
    i.nome, 
    i.tipo, 
    i.data,
    RANK() OVER   
    (PARTITION BY i.loja, i.nome ORDER BY i.data DESC) AS Rank  
FROM vendas I  
WHERE rank=1;
```

GO

Eu não tenho o sql instalado, então fiz de cabeça. para vc entender o comando.
Rank é uma função do sql, no qual fz o ranqueamento. (1,2,3) etc.
partition by são os campos que você quer único, tipo uma chave. 
order by é utilizado para fazer o raqueamento.
Você pode vê que não tem o campo tipo no rank, pq vc não precisa.
Espero que ajude!!!